# CSS Line Breaking with Image

Tags: css, line

As we all know we use `<br>` to break the lines in websites... But I would like to have image as line breaker. Like example:

> Here is some text and I will line break it like this ->
>   -* -* -* -* -* -* -* -* -* -* -*
>  and some more text here

How I can do it?

Comment: In general, don't use `<br />`. Unless you write poetry or something like that.

Comment: This feels more like an `<hr/>` to me rather than a `<br/>`

Comment: I was just thinking that if I want straight line cross the container to separete the lines. How I should do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it a *block* `display`:

```css
img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum <img src="https://placekitten.com/100/100" /> dolar sit amet
```

Comment: I was just thinking that if I want straight line cross the container to separete the lines. How I should do it?

Comment: @Pvtrixx use a `<hr>` element?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, a div element is a block element. Any block element always starts in a new line. So you can create an image that you want to come as the line breaker. Then you wrap it within a div tag, like this

```
<div><img src='YOUR_IMG.jpg' /></div>
```

This should work.